# How to disable collations warning in mysql

Tags: mysql, warnings, collation

A day ago i migrated to another server. After that i always see message

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

at the top of the page. Site language is PHP. I know that database structure is not ideal, but i don't want to change it. The only thing i need is to disable this message. I digg in the code and found that this message appears after call of mysql_query("Set Names utf8") function. I tried to place @ before it and disabled all errors reporting in php.ini. Without any success. I checked manuals and didn't find answer as well. So does anybody know how to disable it? Thanks.

Comment: So you don't want to set proper collations? It doesn't sound wrong to you? Do you know what collation is anyway?

Answer (score 1):

```
alter table `TABLENAME` convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```

also show output from query

```
show variables like '%char%';
```

Comment: I know what collation mean. I don't want to touch database structure because it worked well on the old server. Output for show variables like '%char%';
 is: character_set_client  utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database  utf8
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results  utf8
character_set_server  latin1
character_set_system  utf8

Comment: you need to tune database charset or server default charset/collation, you have no way out if you want to solve problem, not just mask it

Comment: but old server has the same output except character_set_database  latin1

Comment: just changed character_set_database to latin1 on the new server. Problem is still there.

Comment: I converted all databases, tables and fields to utf8/utf8_unicode_ci and message dissapeared.